# Updating progress bar within a multitask function

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to update the progress bar which is on my Form1 using Form1.ProgressBar1.PerformStep() from a class function. I am using the async functions. There are 10 processes running but the progress bar should be updated based on the value of the records read (and later processed) within the `While loop`. It looks like I'm not able to update the GUI using the code below. I have tried `begininvoke` and `invoke` but not luck. Any ideas?

```
 Await Cheque.MultiProcessCheques()

 Public Shared Async Function MultiProcessCheques() As Task
            Dim tasks As New List(Of Task)()
            For i As Integer = 0 To 9
                Dim temp_i As Integer = i
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(Function() Cheque.CopyBinaryValueToFile(temp_i)))
            Next
            Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)
 End Function

 Public Shared Async Function CopyBinaryValueToFile(i As Integer) As Task
            Try
                Using connection = ConnectionController.GetConnection
                    Await connection.OpenAsync()
                    Using command = ConnectionController.GetCommand
                        command.CommandText = ("SELECT ch.RECORDID FROM TABLE WHERE VALUE = '%" & i & "'")
                        command.Connection = connection
                        command.CommandTimeout = 0
                        Using reader As Common.DbDataReader = Await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess)
                            While Await reader.ReadAsync()
                                If reader.HasRows Then

                                End If
' update Progress bar here
                                Form1.ProgressBar1.PerformStep() 
                            End While
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show("1" & ex.ToString)
            End Try
        End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: Is this code running from within Form1?...or a different Class?  Is Form1 the **Startup Object** (you're accessing the "default instance" of Form1 in your code snippet above)?  `Invoke()` is the correct approach.  Most likely you need to **reference the correct instance of Form1**.  Pass a reference to your Form1 instance into the other class so you can `Invoke()` against the correct instance...

Comment: @Idle_Mind I'm calling this class (Cheque) from a button in my Form1 like this: Await Cheque.MultiProcessCheques(). It's a different class.  There's only one project in the solution. How would I pass a reference to Form1 instance as you suggest?

Comment: @Idle_Mind Ok, I believe I understand what you mean. I created a Public oForm1 as New Form1. Then after initializecomponent I have oform1 = me and then referencing the oForm1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a Shared Member to hold the Form1 reference in your Cheque Class, and modify your MultiProcessCheques() function to receive a reference:

```
Public Class Cheque

    Private Shared F1 As Form1

    Public Shared Async Function MultiProcessCheques(ByVal f1 As Form1) As Task
        Cheque.F1 = f1

        ' ... other code ...

    End Function

    Public Shared Async Function CopyBinaryValueToFile(i As Integer) As Task

        ' ... other code ...

        Cheque.F1.Invoke(Sub()
                             Cheque.F1.ProgressBar1.PerformStep()
                         End Sub)

        ' ... other code ...

    End Function

End Class
```

Then pass in "Me" when you call it:

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    ' ... other code ...

    Await Cheque.MultiProcessCheques(Me)

    ' ... other code ...

End Sub
```

Comment: Typical idel_mind always with the right solution. Superb!